# Avoid cross-site scripting (XSS) in vue toasted notification title

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scripting, xss, cross-site

I use [vue-toasted](https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted) when inject js code ex. `"><img src=1 onerror=prompt(document.cookie);>` in input and click submit.

Notification show like that: [image] and popup show with cookie :/ .

and `console.log(response.data.message);` show: 
`Created Site ""><img src=1 onerror=prompt(document.cookie);>" successfully!`

vue is escaping html but `toasted` is not, here is the code:

```
handleFormSubmit: function(response) {
        this.showAddSiteModal = false;
        if (response.data.status === 'success')
        {
            console.log(response.data.message);
            this.$toasted.success(response.data.message); //<<< problem here
            this.addSite(response.data.site);
        }
        else
        {
            this.$toasted.error(response.data.message);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in php side.